# Know if user enabled/disabled check spelling on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

Is there any way to know (*Programmatically*) if a user enabled/disabled check spelling
(**General->Keyboard->check spelling**) ?

Comment: for Mac not iPhone ...https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/SpellCheck/Concepts/SpellChecker.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way you can find this out programatically.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in iOS .
But your generate Red UnderLine for wrong spelling.

```
[textView setSpellCheckingType:UITextSpellCheckingTypeYes];
```